# Implementing classification with rejection and interpreting 2D ambiguous data

Tags: classification, interpretation, scatterplot, boxplot

Let's say we're going to train a classifier with the full data set. There's also a reject logic for ambiguous regions in the data. So, at the end, the final system outputs **reject** or **0** or **1**.  That is, reject data points in regions with high ambiguity, otherwise use the original model predictions.

1. If you were to see a scatterplot with a boxplot accompanying it, how would you interpret the data in this plot?
2. How would you reject ambiguous data points?

[image]

[image]